# using spot instances with dask.distributed

Tags: python, dask

Does dask.distributed support using ec2 spot instances with `dask-ec2`? I didn't see an option to specify for that on http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ec2.html

Comment: I recommend raising an issue at github.com/dask/dask-ec2/issues/new

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't, and `dask-ec2` itself isn't supported anymore. The [Dask maintainers recommend](https://github.com/dask/dask-ec2/issues/28#issuecomment-665062239) the following alternatives:

- [dask-cloudprovider](https://cloudprovider.dask.org/en/latest/)  -- OSS cloud deployment
- [dask-helm](https://helm.dask.org/) and [dask-kubernetes](https://kubernetes.dask.org/en/latest/) -- kubernetes support
- [coiled](https://docs.coiled.io/user_guide/index.html) and [saturncloud](https://www.saturncloud.io/) -- enterprise cloud deployment